# Was the transliteration of the Greek ‘eu’ prefix originally pronounced ‘ev’ in keeping with Greek phonetic structure

Tags: prefixes, transliteration

Why was the the Greek prefix ‘ευ’ meaning ‘good or virtuous’ transliterated in to English as ‘eu’ rather than ‘ev’ as it would have thus carried over its phonetic value?

Notwithstanding, of course, ‘ev-angelic’ which I’m presuming assumed the ‘correct’ phonetic value of ‘ev’ as it is phonologically conditioned. ‘Eua’ would create a clumsy vowel cluster ‘euangelic’ which is not the case in:
Eucharist. Eureka. Eudemon. Eugenic, etc.

So I am wondering if the ‘U’ in the words above, was ever pronounced as a ‘V’.
Evcharist. Evreka. Evdemon. Evgenic, etc.

Comment: I don't know much about Greek, but _eureka_ is said to come 'from  Greek heurēka ‘I have found it’ (from heuriskein ‘find’)'. Isn't the second letter _upsilon_?

Comment: @KateBunting If you look at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B5%E1%BD%95%CF%81%CE%B7%CE%BA%CE%B1#Pronunciation then you can see the evolution of the pronunciation of εὕρηκα from /hěu̯.rɛː.ka/ to /ˈ(h)ew.re̝.ka/ to /ˈe.βri.ka/ to /ˈe.vri.ka/ and similar changes happened to ευ in other examples: [βασιλεύς](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B2%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%B9%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%8D%CF%82#Pronunciation) (master/king) went from /ba.si.lěu̯s/ to /ba.siˈlews/ to /βa.siˈleɸs/ to /va.siˈlefs/

Comment: You are using the term transliteration incorrectly.

Comment: @Henry - So the 'eu' pronunciation, which the English word is based on, predates the 'ev' pronunciation?

Comment: Many "eu" words came via Latin and Old French. [Eucharist](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=Eucharist) comes from late Latin *eucharistia*; "eu" in [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_phonology_and_orthography) generally represented a diphthong, although in other places "u" could be pronounced /w/. This question seems based on a misconception about ancient Greek and Latin.

Comment: @StuartF though it is worth remembering that written Latin did not distinguish between U and V (or between I and J) and did not have a W

Comment: I do not know exactly when it was in the long history of the Greek language that the upsilon in the diphthongs ευ and αυ became a labiodental fricative, even when followed by a consonant, as in Modern Greek. But I suspect it happened too late to precede the loan of many words from Greek to English.

Comment: As to *eureka,* its first syllable is not an example of *eu-* as a prefix meaning good or well: the *eu-* there is part of the stem. And the fabled excited utterance of Archimedes in his bath is more properly rendered as first-person singular perfect indicative active ηὕρηκα, "I have found."

Comment: @BrianDonovan I suspect the change in spoken Greek happened many centuries  before the Renaissance when English academics started borrowing Greek words at a large scale into English, but the English borrowers were using written texts with no idea of how the words were pronounced in the Greek of the time.

Comment: It would take an expert in phonics to explain how (it is now believed) the diphthong 'eu' ('ευ') was pronounced in the 5th century BCE.  This, by the way is further complicated by the variety of Greek dialects and local pronunciations at the time.  The Athenian 'Attic' dialect of Thucydides, Sophocles and Plato did win out in the end but the supposed first historian, Herodotus, wrote in Ionic, the poetry of Sappho was East Aeolic, while the Spartans spoke Doric.  The work on pronunciation has, it is true, concentrated on Attic:  a little like an e as in met and then w (as in wet):  tricky.